# Android Studio 3.4.1 not showing running simulator on mac

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter, cross-platform, simulator

I am learning flutter, recently i updated my android studio and flutter SDK, after that the android studio not showing my running simulator.

Details:-
Android Studio:- 3.4.1

So kindly suggest to fix this issue

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start a device with iOS 11.3